# lateral join with a right join

Tags: postgresql, lateral-join

so I have two tables, A and B.

first I do a lateral join of A with one column (items)

```
select A.id, item->>'id' as item_id, b.id 
from a, jsonb_array_elements(items) rx(item)
```

[image]

then I do a right join with table b (has only 2 rows, with id 1 and 2)

```
select A.id, item->>'id' as item_id, b.id 
from a, jsonb_array_elements(items) rx(item) 
right join b on b.id::varchar = item->>'id'
```

[image]

my main question is, why didn't the right join take out the rows where item_id = 3 and 4? why still null there. On the other hand, if I change the cross lateral join to left lateral join, it solves my problem. But I want to understand the evaluation order in this particular query.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is an associativity problem: you expected `(a join rx) join b` but got `a join (rx join b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the other hand, if I change the cross lateral join to left lateral join, it solves my problem.

You didn't have a cross join to start with, you had a comma join.  Those are not quite identical, as the comma join has lower precedence.  If you change it from a comma join to a true cross join, it also solves the problem.

I think this is probably a bug.  The comma join should throw an error because the "items" column should be unavailable at the point where it is needed.

Comment: Why would `items` be unavailable?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL: "*Table functions appearing in `FROM` can also be preceded by the key word `LATERAL`, but for functions the key word is optional; the function's arguments can contain references to columns provided by preceding `FROM` items in any case.*"

Comment: you're absolutely right! if I change comma to `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`, it solve the problem!

Comment: @Bergi because it amounts to `A cross join (B right join C)`  How can B be right joined to C before the result is cross joined to A, when B is a function which depends on particular rows of A?  Or in other words, where would the implicit LATERAL be?  `A cross join lateral (B right join C)`?  `A cross join (lateral B right join C)`?

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, the implicit lateral is outside of the parenthesis, but it should not be optional there. The implicit lateral should only be applied directly on table function expressions. Care to report a bug?

Answer (score -2):

As I remember, you use RIGHT join to get all the records from right side (table b in your example) and their corresponding records in left side (table a) using the ON clause conditions. If the record in right side doesn't have a corresponding record in left side, then the selected fields FROM left are NULL.

Use LEFT join to get the contrary effect, or switch the tables each other.

If you want get just the exact corresponding records in both tables (sides), use JOIN with the ON clause needed (or INNER JOIN, is the same).

If you use JOIN without the ON clause (or FROM A, B without JOIN OR WHERE), you will get the cartesian product: all records from LEFT side combined (plus) all records from RIGTH side.